# I try to use moment.js in vue3(ts),based vite.it can be used,but i can not use 'zh-cn' in my code.thanks

Tags: momentjs, vuejs3

in main.ts

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/pt';
import 'moment/locale/zh-cn';

console.log(1,moment.locale()); // en
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(2,moment.locale()); // en
moment.locale('zh-CN');
console.log(3,moment.locale()); // pt-BR

console.log(moment.locales())

const app = createApp(App)


app.config.globalProperties.$moment = moment
```

It can not be changed 'zh-cn',moment.locale() run result is also 'en',use 'moment.locale('zh-CN')' or 'moment.locale('zh-cn')' or 'moment.locale('zh-Cn')' is not useful.

Answer (score -1):

I try to using day.js instead of momentjs.It can be use chinese in my code.
In main.ts.

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import isLeapYear from 'dayjs/plugin/isLeapYear' // 导入插件
import relativeTime from'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime'
import 'dayjs/locale/zh-cn' // 导入本地化语言
dayjs.extend(relativeTime)
dayjs.extend(isLeapYear) // 使用插件
dayjs.locale('zh-cn') // 使用本地化语言
console.log(dayjs().from(dayjs('1990-01-01')))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as unclear as the question is.